# Crystal Reports - Create Running Total that Excludes Other Running Total Values

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Is there a way to create a running total that filters out values used in other running totals? Something like:

```
where not in(Running_Total_1)
```

I don't want to have to go through all my running totals (there are 16) and copy/paste/alter all the formulas.

Comment: Where do you want yo filter?

Comment: I assume it would have to be in the formula under the "Evaluate" section of the "Edit Running Total" menu.

Comment: I am not sure what is your requirement but 'Evaluate' in runningtotal is something that tells when you want to evaluate the condition...but not to skip other running totals

Comment: No, you can't reference a Running Total like a set. The best you can do is negate the "Evaluate on" formula between the two.